# How do I silence warnings ubiquitous in Python package compilation?

Tags: python, gcc, gcc-warning

Any time I `pip install` a package that has some C libraries that need compilation (e.g. Numpy), I get flooded with warnings like the following:

```
    /home/visitors/ntimkovich/Projects/Waldo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1629:1: warning: ‘_import_array’ defined 
but not used [-Wunused-function]
    /home/visitors/ntimkovich/Projects/Waldo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:241:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but 
not used [-Wunused-function]
```

I remember reading something about how to configure the build environment so that many GCC warnings that are meaningless to Python code get squelched, but alas I forget where, and I don't know enough about GCC to begin.